# What is this little tooltip that refuses to go away?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I noticed a strange tooltip at the taskbar (near the clock). I don't remember when it appeared and what triggered it. But it just doesn't seem to go away - no matter wherever I click (other taskbar icon, desktop etc)

[image]

Is this something that I should be worried about because [this](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=RXXCXZ23DZaRwgOymZmQCw&q=icn_close-2&oq=icn_close-2&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0.1567.4477..5751...0.0..0.143.1004.10j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131j0i10j0i30j0i10i30j0i8i10i30j0i8i30.LKWkANCUAtc) search seems to suggest that it could be malware.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather unlikely that it's caused by malware.

This tooltip likely comes from your browser. Try to close it.

If it's still there, then you've hit a rare Windows bug where tooltip "sticks" with full or partial opacity. It can be removed by rebooting or by changing your screen resolution to a different one, then back.

Comment: Another possible faster option to get rid of it, is a windows video driver reset, by hitting CTRL-WIN-SHIFT-B